# JMeter not extract values from CSV file

Tags: csv, jmeter

### I just mentioned 2 user

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVtUE.png]

### CSV File-With Two User credentials

[image]

### CSV file Configutration

[image]

### HTTP Request Configuration

[image]

1. Please check and provide the solution how it comes
2. I have done all the steps but why JMETER not extracting the CSV values.

Comment: Add actual code. Not screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

AS I am observing from your attached image you have added the CSV Data Config file `**after**` recording controller which need to come `before` Thread Group.

[image]

Comment: Hi Vikas, Thanks for your suggestion!. I have did the same It's really working!  Thanks Once Again!